# Can I put buttons on a drawn rectangle in Java?

Tags: java, button, draw

I want to create and implement a Game Over screen to my game.
Is it possible to just do this by creating an extra class "GameOver" which has a new draw object which just draws a black rectangle set to the middle of the screen and to have some buttons like "new game" ON the drawn rectangle?

Or what is the best way to go?

My game is running on a JFrame.

If you want to see specific code, let me know, I got a lot of classes and so it would be difficult to show everything and I thought its not actually necessary for this question.

Comment: You could but then you would have to use absolute positioning of  your buttons to ensure they remain inside the rectangle.  I would recommend just using a JPanel to hold the buttons and have the panel background the color of  your choice.  Then add the panel to the frame using an appropriate layout manager.  Imo, it would be much easier.

Comment: @WJS thank you. And how do I do the Game Over Screen itself beside the Buttons? Cant find good resources to that.

Comment: *I want to create and implement a Game Over screen to my game* Just use a modal JDialog to display the text and buttons. You can make the dialog undecorated if you wish. Another option is to use a "glass pane". Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you might want to do.  You should check [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more details.
Especially `layout managers`, `custom painting`, and `listeners for handling events`.
I used some anonymous classes where explicit ones would probably be preferred.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameScreen {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GameScreen().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        
        // this was quick and dirty.  Best to have separate classes with proper overrides, etc.
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 130);
            }
        };
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game") {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            }
        };
        
        // shared attributes
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        JTextField text = new JTextField();
        Color orange = Color.orange;
        Color maroon = new Color(176, 48, 96);
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 80));
        Font font = new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 30);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;  // in the middle
        gbc.gridy = 1;  // of the screen
        
        // game over stuff
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setForeground(orange);
        text.setBackground(maroon);
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setText("     GAME OVER!");
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.addActionListener(ae -> System.exit(0)); // more complicated code should an
                                                      // inner class for this.
        
        //new game stuff
        JTextField newGameText = new JTextField();
        newGameText.setText("READY TO RUMBLE!");
        newGameText.setFont(font);
        newGameText.setForeground(orange);
        newGameText.setBackground(maroon);
        JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
        
        
        newGame.addActionListener(ae -> {
            panel.setVisible(false);
            frame.add(newGameText, gbc);
        });
        
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(quit);
        panel.add(newGame);
        
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel, gbc);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.repaint();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use another method `public boolean gameOver()` to detect what your winning condition is. Then you can return true or false using the if statements inside the method. For the screen, you can stop the game loop and then take the current frame and draw another black or gray rectangle on top of it with JButtons to restart the game/level. You should call this gameOver method once every frame.